# saxon9-dom.jar not found only when running junit

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, xml-parsing

We're trying to run a junit test case for a method which is using saxon9-dom.jar. In eclipse,we just right click on the test class/run as junit and it throws the error "DOMSource cannot be processed: check that saxon9-dom.jar is on the classpath".

The method is working when called from the main class on a normal run. The saxon9-dom.jar was/is in the project classpath(checked both,in eclipse and opening the .classpath file). It has been added again separately under 'libraries'.It's on the 'run configurations/classpath' too. It was even put within the classpath for the 'environment variables' of the PC...nothing works, always the same result/error.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is there a stacktrace where exactly is the error appearing?

Comment: @MatthewFarwell
I'll copy a bit from dev machine:
(all normal before,'irrelevant')
(in a sudden,in red)
"Error
    DOMSource cannot be processed:check that saxon9-dom.jar is on the classpath"
...this happens when calling "tr.transform(source,streamXml)".the tr transform object seems not to be null looking at the debugger (no Nullpointer exception either).The source was created from the doc object,which we populated with the values we wanted(working if not junit)

Comment: When you launch JUnit is the .jar in the classpath for that launch configuration?